# How to get particular database from large mysql dump?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have the `localhost.sql` back up which takes 750 MB in size.....This dump has more number of databases in it. Need to take only one database from that sql file. Is it possible to do that ? Do we have tool for that ? I have searched many ways. but could not able to get my db from that.

Then I have tried this `split -l 100000 localhost.sql` to split the sql. This splits more txt file.By using these text file How could i get my database ? or suggest best way to get my particular db from sql dump

Kindly help.

Comment: split text with `sed` by `CREATE DATABASE` statements

Comment: How did you get your extract ? wouldn't it be easier to make it for the specific database you want ?

Comment: @tsabz Actually dump which i have now had taken at last year for backup. now OS has re installed in this.Need to get particular DB in server.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract one database from the full dump using this command

```
mysql -u root -p –-one-database targetdb < fulldump.sql
```

Comment: Whole sql dump could not be able to import in server

Comment: You could try this perl script to extract the database from the sql dump : http://www.linuxplayer.org/2012/05/extract-databases-or-tables-from-mysqldump